# laravel wont work with $ ? in the url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

i have offers api from a website and this return this url

```
http://mylaravelsite/offers/done/?id=100&oid=12&o_name=YurMobile-FI&amount=10cy_name=Qoins&user_id=1&sig=606a5e547ed5c607b10f97a5958f4c38&payout=5.250
```

i used this routing code

```
Route::get('/offers/data/{data}', "HomeController@offersdone");
```

but the url showed every time

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

What do i wrong or is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this route:

```
Route::get('/offers/data/{data}', "HomeController@offersdone");
```

Just:

```
Route::get('/offers/data', "HomeController@offersdone");
```

In the controller do something like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function offersdone() {
        if (!Input::has("id")) {
            return response("Invalid id");
        }
        $data = Input::all();
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

Will print

```
array:7 [▼
  "id" => "100"
  "oid" => "12"
  "o_name" => "YurMobile-FI"
  "amount" => "10cy_name=Qoins"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "sig" => "606a5e547ed5c607b10f97a5958f4c38"
  "payout" => "5.250"
]
```

Also you can use `Request` in `public function offersdone(Request request)`

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is here that you are running completely different url. You have defined in your route the following url:

```
/offers/data/{data}
```

and you run url:

```
http://mylaravelsite/offers/done/
```

and it should be probably:

```
http://mylaravelsite/offers/data/done/
```

**EDIT**

Reading your question I'm also not sure what character do you mean - is it `?` or `$` (`$` is not in url you provided so probably you mean `?`). I can ensure you that when you run the correct url you can use query string (extra variables after `?` sign)

Comment: i have only now the `?id=100`and `&oid=12&o_name=YurMobile-FI&amount=10cy_name=Qoins&user_id=1&sig=606a5e547ed5c607b10f97a5958f4c38&payout=5.250` how can i she rewrite to `/100/12/YurMobile-FI/10/Qoins/1/606a5e547ed5c607b10f97a5958f4c38/5.250` ?

Comment: What do you want to rewrite? If you need to pass extra parameters you can use those in query string and then in laravel you can use `$request->input('oid')` for instance.

Comment: the `?` remove's my `/`. that mustn't